# Are questions about Apple Music on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are we allowed to ask questions about using Apple Music or other music streaming apps here? I would say that most music fans nowadays use streaming services, but I don't decide if it's on-topic here. Should I ask somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For support questions related to Apple Music, it would be best to directly contact Apple or post on their dedicated support forums. Ditto for other services like Spotify, Google Play, etc.

It is possible to have a general question about streaming services — say about how royalties are decided. Such questions can definitely be on-topic here. As an example:

- [What digital medium should I choose when buying music to maximize artists' profits?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3655/3955)

It is also possible that a question asks about how to use streaming services optimally, taking up a specific one only as an example. Such a question can also be on-topic. For example:

- [How to find "recommended" playlists in Spotify?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/15/3955)
- [How can I discover new music based on what I have downloaded as mp3](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6375/3955)

So, a good rule of thumb is:

- Support questions: off-topic
- Music experience/culture (in particular, from a *fan*'s perspective): on-topic

<sub>Also, it goes without saying, but obligatory disclaimer: merely being on-topic does not guarantee that a question will be well-received.</sub>